# How to find empty tables? PL/SQL Vs T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want to list empty tables using T-SQL.

I can do it in PL/SQL as below but I am facing Error in T-SQL.

```
 -- Oracle PLSQL :: TABLES HAVING EMPTY DATA
 SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  CNT PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  FOR C IN ( SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES 
  WHERE OWNER='xxxx'   ) 
LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Select Count(*) From "' || C.TABLE_NAME || '" where rownum=1'
            INTO CNT;
    IF( CNT = 0 ) THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( C.TABLE_NAME );
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Getting Error in T-SQL

```
DECLARE @tblnme VARCHAR(128) 
DECLARE @CNT NUMERIC(5)
DECLARE @sqlstr NVARCHAR(200)

DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT name FROM sys.objects WHERE name IN ('t1','t2')

OPEN c1
FETCH c1 into @tblnme

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
@sqlstr = N'SELECT TOP 1 @CNT =1  FROM' +@tblnme
exec sp_executesql @sqlstr 

IF @CNT IS NULL
print @tblnme+' is empty'

FETCH c1 into @tblnme
END

CLOSE c1
DEALLOCATE c1
```

Error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near '@sqlstr'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CLOSE'.
```

Please advise.
Also let me know if any other best way same can be achieved in T-SQL.
I want list only empty tables by checking minimum 1 row exist or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are missing a space after the FROM in `@sqlstr`.

Comment: After giving a space   ( ... FROM  ' + @tblnme ) also getting same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using SQL Server catalog views to avoid scanning the tables to get the row count. Although the count will not be transactionally consistent, it should be good enough for the purpose of finding empty tables. This will also allow you to avoid the cursor.

```
SELECT
      QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) AS TableName
FROM sys.tables AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM sys.partitions AS p
    WHERE 
        p.object_id = t.object_id
        AND p.index_id IN(0,1)
        AND p.rows > 0
    )
ORDER BY TableName;
```

**UPDATE:**

The reason your T-SQL cursor script erred is because of the missing `SET` command for the SQL string variable. Below is an example with that fix that also addresses objects in different schemas and a few other tweaks.

```
DECLARE
      @tblnme NVARCHAR(261) 
    , @CNT NUMERIC(5)
    , @sqlstr NVARCHAR(200);

DECLARE c1 CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(name)
    FROM sys.tables
    WHERE name IN ('t1','t2');

OPEN c1;
FETCH c1 INTO @tblnme;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sqlstr = N'SELECT TOP 1 @CNT = 1  FROM ' + @tblnme;
    SET @CNT = NULL;
    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlstr, N'@CNT int OUTPUT', @CNT = @CNT OUTPUT;

    IF @CNT IS NULL
        PRINT @tblnme+' is empty';
    FETCH c1 INTO @tblnme;
END;

CLOSE c1;
DEALLOCATE c1;
```

Comment: Dan, The SQL you have shared is useful. However, I believe sys.partitions will be updated by stats gathering etc.

Comment: @VeeraV, not sure what you mean by stats updating sys.partitions. Can you elaborate?

Comment: In Oracle, sys tables will be updated with the latest rowcount of table in dictionary views after gathering statistics. So we can get a count of records from dictionary views  (select NUM_ROWS from dba_tables) but can't be accurate at the time of issuing count. I am not sure when this sys.partitions will be updated and whether stats gathering concept is there or not in SQL Server. So only for PL/SQL code also I used rowNUM=1 for a correct result.

Comment: SQL Server maintains `sys.partitions' as insert/delete statements occur. Although, it's not guaranteed to be 100 percent accurate, it nearly always is in my experience and I've personally never seen zero rows reported for a non-empty table. You can run `DBCC UPDATEUSAGE` to update the counts if you suspect otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the detail Dan, I am still looking why the above code throwing error, what mistake i did and how it can be corrected.